# How to get the value of the next column using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I need to match the column A and fetch its corresponding next value in next column B.
For example , I have to check if 1 is matched in column A, If true then print "First Page"

Similarly for all the values in column A has to be matched with say X , if true, then print its next value in column B.

Example:

[image: Example csv]

Comment: Your question is really not clear. What do you want to do? What is the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: Expected Output - if i give the input as 67 , then SIXTY SEVENTH should be displayed. Similarly for all the values in A column , its corresponding B column values should print

Comment: OP might need to print *ordinal words* of numerical values available in column A in column B.

Answer (score 2):

By using df.iloc you can can get the row or column you want by index.
By using mask you can filter the data frame to get the row you want (where column a == some value) and take the value in the second column by df.iloc[0,1].

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4], 'col2': [4,3,2,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2
0   1       4
1   2       3
2   3       2
3   4       1

# a is the value in the first column and df is the data frame
def a2b(a,df):
    return df[df.iloc[:,0]==a].iloc[0,1]
a2b(2,df)
```

returns 3